# Does not show forms errors in Django

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-3.0

I want to show the required errors but not showing them. I made custom errors in form.py but it does not show either my current or default and why?

When I submit a blank form I want it to appear, my created error

this is my code -->

**home.html**

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Sign up Form</h2>
<div class="frm">
<form method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form}}
    
  
  <button type="submit">sign up</button>
</form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()



class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    username.error_messages['required'] = ('Username field is required')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
                field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'inp'
            for field in self.fields.values():
                field.error_messages = {'required':'The field {fieldname} is required'.format(
                    fieldname=field.label)} 
            

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2','mob', )
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect


from django.contrib.auth.forms import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login


def home(request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if request.method=="POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'form': form})

def about(request):
    return render (request, 'home/about.html')
```

who can help me?
I searched a lot on Google but could not find a solution

Comment: Where's your view.py?

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna I added and can you see?

Comment: `form = SignUpForm(request.POST)` it should be `form = SignUpForm()` in views

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna not changed. When I open the page it shows but when I submit it disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a clean form without the invalid data, when your form is invalid.
It seems your `else` block is not correctly indented.

```
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:  # << change indentation
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py,  how you call the form is wrong, and also how you pass `POST` request. It should be like this

```
def home(request):
    form = SignUpForm()    # here
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST) # and here

        if form.is_valid():
            ...
```

or this,

```
def home(request):
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)    # here
        if request.method=="POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                ...
```

The other main issue is mentioned in [Håken Lid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65493521/8388057)'s answer.

Comment: not change.  When I open the page it shows but when I submit it disappears